# Geocomplete cities without country

Tags: geolocation, geocomplete

i am using Google Geocomplete to auto suggest my visitors when typing in cities.

It works well, but however it suggests country next to the city. For example, if i start to type Barce, it will suggest Barcelona, Spain. I need only Barcelona, without the country.

Does somebody know how to tell Geocomplete to show only cities without the country?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too faced the same problem

Here is the my solution, I hope this will help you.

**1) Declare the option variable and types property.**

for example,

```
var option = { types: ['(cities)'] };
```

**and,**

```
$("#input").geocomplete(option)
.geocomplete()
```

**and then,**

```
.bind("geocode:result", function(event, reuslt) {
    console.log(result.name);
})
```

**result.name is only show city name.**

so, .bind inner function block add the this line.

```
$("#input").val(result.name);
```